# Unable to acccess web API using powershell for ADFS authentication

Tags: powershell, api, single-sign-on, adfs, invoke-webrequest

I am trying to fetch the data from a site. When i log in with a browser it is redirecting me to adfs.sts.com then redirecting to the site automatically.
When i am trying to connect to same site with powershell it is giving below error:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
        <noscript>
            <p>
                <strong>Note:</strong> Since your browser does not support JavaScript,
                you must press the Continue button once to proceed.
            </p>
        </noscript>

        <form action="https&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;sts.lseg.com&#x2f;adfs&#x2f;ls&#x2f;" method="post">
            <div>
```

It is also opening browser when the Invoke-Webrequest is being called.

Can you please assist how to connect to such sites with powershell where ADFS authentication.